# redux-persist - how do you blacklist/whitelist nested state

Tags: nested, state, blacklist, redux-persist

So I have a credentials object which contains a password and a username

```
payload: Object
  credentials: Object
    password: ""
    username: ""
```

and I want to blacklist password in the reducer configuration, something like

```
const authPersistConfig = {
    key: 'AuthReducer',
    storage: storage,
    blacklist: ['credentials.password']
};
```

If I use this code, both the credential states end up being blacklisted. I want to persist the username but not the password.

It might be that redux-persist only persists top-level state or it might be a syntax error, or something else entirely - any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NPM package called `redux-persist-transform-filter` as described in `redux-persist` [issue #277 - Whitelist reducer subproperty only?](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/277)

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want not completely remove the keys but just clear any of data in any nested state objects, here is example using **createTransform** from **'redux-persist'**

[How to make redux-persist blacklist for nested state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483934/how-to-make-redux-persist-blacklist-for-nested-state)

Answer (score 1):

You can do nested persit config.

```
const rootPersistConfig: any = {
  key: "root",
  timeout: 500,
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  blacklist: ["credentials"],
};
```

```
const credentialsPersistConfig: any = {
  key: "credentials",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ["username"],
};
```

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  credentials: persistReducer(credentialsPersistConfig, CredentialReducer),
});
```

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer);
```

Comment: Password should be blacklisted in this case, right?

Comment: I misunderstood it. but now I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of persist root key like this :

```
    const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}
```

We can use different reducer key:

```
 const userPersistConfig = {
  key: 'userReducer',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['user', 'isLoading']
}
const cartPersistConfig = {
  key: 'cart',
  storage
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  cart: persistReducer(cartPersistConfig, cart),
  filter,
  userReducer: persistReducer(userPersistConfig, userReducer),
  wishlist,
  
})
```

store.js file:

```
 const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
        return getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: false,
        }).concat(apiSlice.middleware);
    },
});
const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either pick or omit to whitelist or blacklist any nested value of a particular one-level store entry.
Here's an example:

```
let blacklistTransform = createTransform((inboundState, key) => {
    if (key === 'credentials') {
        return omit(inboundState, ['password']);
    } else {
        return inboundState;
    }
});

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    blacklist: ['credentials'], // Avoid credentials entry
    transforms: [blacklistTransform],
};
```

Whitelist example:

```
// Just persist dropdown default values
const whitelistTransform = createTransform((inboundState, key) => {
    // Select values from the route reducer
    if (key === 'route') {
        return pick(inboundState, [
            'lastSelectedSchoolYear , lastSelectedSite',
            'lastSelectedState',
        ]);
    }
    return inboundState;
});

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    transforms: [whitelistTransform],
};
```

Comment: Where is the `omit` coming from?

Comment: Lodash: https://docs-lodash.com/v4/omit/

Answer (score 0):

I recently released [an open-source package called Redux Deep Persist](https://github.com/PiotrKujawa/redux-deep-persist), which can be very helpful in creating Redux Persist config for nested state no matter how deep it is. It can help you in this specific situation.

This notation `blacklist: ['credentials.password']` is only allowed when you use *getPersistConfig* method.

Here is what your config would look like:

```
    import { getPersistConfig } from 'redux-deep-persist';
    import storage from "redux-persist/es/storage/session";

    const config = getPersistConfig({
        key: 'root',
        storage,
        blacklist: [
            'credentials.password',
        ],
        rootReducer, // your root reducer must be also passed here
        ... // any other props from the original redux-persist config omitting the stateReconciler
    })
```

You can read more in the official documentation of redux-deep-persist
https://github.com/PiotrKujawa/redux-deep-persist/blob/master/README.md